# Does HP Fortify refer NIST NVD CVE database?

Tags: security, fortify

NVD is the US government repository of vulnerability information known till date. Does HP Fortify refer to the NIST NVD CVE database?

Answer (score 0):

No, Fortify is a static code scanner which scans your code and produces a report which documents potential security vulnerabilities.

If you want to scan code for libraries that may have CVEs then try the OWASP Dependency Checker.